# What libboost suffix is proper for Release/Debug project settings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I am following some tutorial that explains I should add libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib as library that my program will link with.
Problem I have is that IDK what are the proper mappings for Debug/Release options in Visual Studio and extension of the libraries avaliable.
For example I have this extensions(suffixes) available:

ll libboost_chrono*
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  327948 Dec  5 17:54 libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_62.lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 2099844 Dec  5 17:56 libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib

(dont get confused by ll, I am on Win machine)

Comment: `gd` is the debug one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of the tags is explained in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming):

- **s** – linking statically to the C++ standard library and compiler runtime support libraries.
- **g** – using debug versions of the standard and runtime support libraries.
- **y** – using a special debug build of Python.
- **d** – building a debug version of your code.
- **p** – using the STLPort standard library rather than the default one supplied with your compiler.

So, the file `libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_62.lib` is the runtime version (supporting multithreading), and `libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib` is the debug version, using the debug runtime libraries.

---

Also the size is a good hint, the debug builds are usually larger.

Comment: what is the difference between g and d? g refers to libraries that libboost uses, and d to libboost code itself?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You got that right. For the libraries used, it's primarily the Visual C++ runtime that's of concern.